# Repository pattern - EF Core returns null to foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I have this repository implementation:

```
using mediere_API.DataLayer.Entities;
using mediere_API.DataLayer.Repository.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace mediere_API.DataLayer.Repository.Implementations
{
    public class RepositoryBase<T> : IDisposable, IRepositoryBase<T> where T : BaseEntity, new()
    {
        private readonly DbContext _db;
        private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

        protected RepositoryBase(EfDbContext context)
        {
            _db = context;
            _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        }

        public async Task<IList<T>> GetAll(bool asNoTracking = false, bool includeDeleted = false)
        {
            var query = includeDeleted
               ? _dbSet
               : _dbSet.Where(entity => entity.DeletedAt == null);

            return asNoTracking
                ? await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()
                : await query.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetById(int id, bool asNoTracking = false, bool includeDeleted = false)
        {
            return includeDeleted
                ? await GetRecords(asNoTracking).FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id)
                : await GetRecords(asNoTracking).FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id && e.DeletedAt == null);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(T record)
        {
            if (_db.Entry(record).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                _db.Attach(record);
                _db.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
        }

        public virtual void Update(T record)
        {
            if (_db.Entry(record).State == EntityState.Detached)
                _db.Attach(record);

            _db.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public void Delete(T record)
        {
            if (record != null)
            {
                record.DeletedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                Update(record);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _db?.Dispose();
        }

        protected IQueryable<T> GetRecords(bool asNoTracking = false, bool includeDeleted = false)
        {
            var result = includeDeleted ?
                _dbSet
                :
                _dbSet.Where(e => e.DeletedAt == null);

            return asNoTracking ? result.AsNoTracking() : result;
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I have this Entity

```
using mediere_API.Dtos;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace mediere_API.DataLayer.Entities
{
    public class Localitate : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required]
        public string Nume { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int JudetId { get; set; }
        public virtual Judet judet { get; set; }

        public Localitate() { }
    }
}
```

I observed that I don't get the foreign keys in my objects.

In order to get all the objects with their FKs, I decided to add this this method in the repository for that collection:

```
public async Task<List<Localitate>> GetLocalitatiBasicAsync()
        {
            return await base.GetRecords(true).Select(l => new Localitate()
            {
                Id = l.Id,
                Nume = l.Nume,
                judet = l.judet
            }).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Is this the best solution? And what would be the difference between using this select with judet too vs using the .include() method to include judet?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you implementing the repository anti-pattern in the first place? It's redundant because `DbSet<T>` and `DbContext` already *is* your repository.

Comment: @Dai this is how I've been taught ASP.NET. Do you have any article regarding what you've just said? It would help me a lot.

Comment: https://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2012/03/05/The-Generic-Repository-Is-An-Anti-Pattern.aspx https://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/ https://www.infoworld.com/article/3117713/design-patterns-that-i-often-avoid-repository-pattern.html https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/91916

Comment: @Dai got it. Thanks. About my problem, why is that happening though?

Comment: Which properties are foreign-keys?

Comment: Judet is a foreign key

Comment: Are you saying `JudetId == 0` or `Judet == null` ?

Comment: Specify the exact version of EF Core.

Comment: See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). The `virtual` modifier is used for [lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy). Have you added a Proxies package or ILazyLoader?

Comment: But the best and most frequently used way to load related data is eager loading.

Comment: @Dai Judet == null.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I'm on EF Core 6.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Didn't know that about virtual. Thank you!